# Symfony 4.4 Event Listener Error (MongoDB)

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine, event-listener

I'm trying to create a listener to when a new Rating is created. I followed all the documentation but I keep getting the same error:
Argument 1 passed to "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::dispatch()" must be an instance of "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event", "App\Event\AverageRatingEvent" given.

I'm trying to use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event in the event but it keeps saying that it is deprecated and according to documents to use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event instead.

I register my event in the services and the following is my event, eventlistener and class

**Class Rating**

```
class RatingApiController extends AbstractController
{
        
    /**
     * @Route("api/rating/create", name="CreateRating",  methods={"POST"})
     * @param DocumentManager $dm
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EventDispatcher $eventDispatcher
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     * @throws MongoDBException
     * 
     */
    public function addRating(Request $request, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $response = [];

        $form = $this->
        createForm(RatingType::class, new Rating() ,array('csrf_protection' => false));  
        
        $request = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        
        
        $form->submit($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
        
           $rating = $form->getData();

           $this->documentManager->persist($rating);
           $this->documentManager->flush();
           
           $averageRatingEvent = new AverageRatingEvent($rating);
           $eventDispatcher->dispatch( AverageRatingEvent::NAME, $averageRatingEvent);
            

           $status = 200;
           $response = ["status" => $status, "success" => true, "data" => $rating->getId()];
           // return $this->redirectToRoute('rating_list'); 
       }



}
```

**Event**

```
<?php
namespace App\Event;

use App\Document\Rating;
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;

class AverageRatingEvent extends Event
{
    /**
     * @var Rating $rating
     */
    protected $rating;

    public const NAME = "average.rating";
    
    public function __construct(Rating $rating)
    {
        $this->rating = $rating;        
    }

    public function getRating()
    {
        return $this->rating;
    }
    
}
```

**Listener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use App\Document\Rating;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class AverageRatingListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $document = $args->getObject();
        if(!$document instanceof Rating)
        return;
    }


    public function RatingCreated()
    {
        dump("Hello a rating was just added");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doctrine Events and Symfony Events are two different things, you shouldn't need to dispatch a sf event to use doctrine events. And by the way, your `dispatch` arguments are backwards: `dispatch($averageRatingEvent, AverageRatingEvent::NAME);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside AverageRatingEvent you extend Event.

The use needs to be changed from

```
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event;
```

to

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
```